# Old Fluke 23 service manual?

Tags: multimeter, calibration

I'm looking for my old Fluke 23 service or calibration manual but all the Fluke 23 I find in a google search are the series II or series III. Mine is the oldest I guess, it has no series. Thanks.

UPDATE: Added pictures as requested. Left: With holder front, Middle:No holder front, Right: No holder back

[image: Fluke 23 DMM]

Comment: Do you have a picture of it? I see many "fluke 23" which are different when googling about it.

Comment: Rodo - Hi, I see this is already getting "close" votes. Test equipment is [neither in the clearly on-topic list, nor in the clearly off-topic list](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), but it seems some in the community don't think the question fits here. However I have some experience looking for exactly the same manual. Would you like me to spin-up a chat room so we can discuss, without being encumbered by the on-topic constraints?